# do not reload page when modal is open

Tags: javascript, ajax, modal-dialog

this is my very first question here. I want to prevent reloading a page from browser reload button only when a modal is open. otherwise it can be reloaded. I should show an alert saying that the modal should be closed before reloading or something like that.

HTML:

```
<div id="newwr" class="modal newwr">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Create a WR</h4>
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        if (modal.isOpen()) {
          alert("Modal should be closed before reloading the page");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: first show your code here. Also try to use **jQuery** . On modal close try to make a **confirm alert** dailog to prevent refreshing page.

Comment: Hi @SHAZ, I showed some of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `onbeforeunload` to provide that kind of response.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (modal.isOpen()) {
      return "Modal should be closed before reloading or something...";
    }
}
```

You'll need to determine whether the modal is open or not somehow. You could keep track of the state internally (as I've tried to show with pseudocode here), or by checking the DOM to see if your modal is present and/or visible.

As stated in the comments, we can provide more specific help once we know more about your code, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response @double.emms, but it's not working. I'm using window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (modal.isOpen()) {
      alert("Modal should be closed before reloading the page");
    }
}</code>

Comment: Very sorry. I had a typo in there at first. It should not be calling `alert`, just returning the message. It has been edited.

Comment: still not working. i provided some of the code to help yourself

Comment: OK, it works fine now. It works different as I intended before but you definetly guided me to the right direction. Thanks a lot